# php class inheritance private method not calling properly in child (extended) class

Tags: php, oop, extends, private-methods

```
class A
{
    public function x()
    {
        echo "Public function in class A<br />";
    }
    private function y()
    {
        echo "Private function in class A<br />";
    }
    public function expose()
    {
        $this->x();
        $this->y();
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function x()
    {
        echo "Public function in class B<br />";
    }
    private function y()
    {
        echo "Private function in class B<br />";
    }
}
$y = new A;
$y->expose();

$z = new B;
$z->expose();
```

The instantioation of class A produces the following outcome:
"Public function in class A
Private function in class A"

The instantioation of class B produces the following outcome:
"Public function in class B
Private function in class A"

can anyone explain the out come of the instantioation of class B?
Shouldn't it call "B's" private method and not the parent method of class A?

Answer (score 4):

That's because private members cannot be inherited.

Your `B` class doesn't have the `expose()` method defined, so it will call `A`'s method, which calls its own private `y()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Something else to consider. If you want to see something similar to the behavior you were originally expecting, you can make y() protected instead of private. By doing this, the protected method in class B will be visible by methods in class A and will run the class be method as you expected. However, the protected methods in class A and B will still remain inaccessible from an outside call like $z->y();

```
class A
{
    public function x()
    {
        echo "Public function in class A<br />";
    }
    protected function y()
    {
        echo "Protected function in class A<br />";
    }
    public function expose()
    {
        $this->x();
        $this->y();
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function x()
    {
        echo "Public function in class B<br />";
    }
    protected function y()
    {
        echo "Protected function in class B<br />";
    }
}
$y = new A;
$y->expose();

$z = new B;
$z->expose();
```

will result in:

```
Public function in class A
Protected function in class A
Public function in class B
Protected function in class B
```